# Is there standard format for representing date/time in URIs?

Tags: api, datetime, uri

I am building an API endpoint that accepts DateTime as a parameter.
It is recommended not to use `:` character as part of the URI, so I can't simply use ISO 8601 format.

So far I have considered two formats:

**A) Exclamation mark as minute delimiter:**

`http://api.example.com/resource/2013-08-29T12!15`

Looks unnatural and even with clear documentation, API consumers are bound to make mistakes.

**B) URI segment per DateTime part:**

`http://api.example.com/resource/2013/08/29/12/15`

Looks unreadable. Also, once I add further numeric parameters - it will become incomprehensible!

Is there standard/convention for for representing date/time in URIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use the data interchange standard format.

Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: My examples already use ISO 8601. The question is how to I represent it in a URI. Character `:` is not recommended.

Comment: Also separation characters are a part of the standard. For example you can't write 2013$08$29 and say it follows the standard. To express day time the standard 8601 allows basic format [hh][mm][ss] and extended format is [hh]:[mm]:[ss] so if you don't want to use : as separator you can write using basic format and still adhere to standard. To conclude, I'd use http://api.example.com/resource/2013-08-29T121500.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:` in URI paths.

The colon is a reserved character, but it has no delimiting role in the path segment. So the [following](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-2.2) should apply:

> If a reserved character is found in a URI component and no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that character's encoding in US-ASCII.

There is only one [exception for relative-path references](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-4.2):

> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that") cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-path reference.

But [note](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2009May/0025.html) that some encoding libraries might percent-encode the colon anyway.